# Dynamic CGridview column Issue

Tags: jquery, yii, cgridview

How to display dynamic H:i:s example (2h30m12s) in CGridview columns? Is there anyway to acheive this?

i am showing how much time user online dynamically,so Hour,minutes,seconds should change dynamically in grid, eg: time = duration + (now - start); So i want dynamic run of H:i:s instead of page refresh.Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: You can display timestamp in combination with jquery timeago plugin: http://timeago.yarp.com

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 array(
       'name'    => 'date',
       'value'   => 'date("H:i:s",strtotime($data->date))'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
setDate();
setInterval(setDate, 1000);
function setDate(){
    var data = new Date();
    $("#CGridview").text(data.getHours()+":"+data.getMinutes()+":"+data.getSeconds());
}
```

need HTML :

```
<div id="CGridview"></div>
```

Comment: i want to update multiple cgridview columns without page refresh lively how to perform that?

Comment: how to call jquery function in                                   array(
 'name' =>session_duraiton' ,                                   'value'=> (here JQuery function to update time dynamically),

Comment: this function isn't for jQuery or i don'nt know! 
i know jQuery i don't know cgridview !!